# Is there a software that I could plug-in into my web site to give e-learning classes?

Tags: web-applications

Does any one nows any e-learning solution that I could use into my site ? I'm trying not to create something from scratch. :-)

UPDATE: Is there something like http://www.knewton.com/ ? Or even close to that ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers ! Being more specific is does anyone knows if  theres a software that does what http://www.knewton.com/ does ? Doesn't matter if its not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers but what [Adobe Acrobat Connect Pro](http://www.adobe.com/br/products/acrobatconnectpro/) is what I was looking for. Thanks again !

Answer (score 4):

[Moodle](http://moodle.org/) is a platform for building online classes. It's free and Open Source. It's built using PHP. Check the [about page](http://docs.moodle.org/en/About_Moodle) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you want but [Moodle](http://moodle.org) is an open source course management system.

Some of its fetures include
 - forum
 - multi course management
 - class registration
 - chat
 - authorisation layers

Have a look at the [demo](http://demo.moodle.org/)

You could also check out

- [Efront](http://www.efrontlearning.net/)
- [joomlaLMS](http://www.joomlalms.com/)

or if you have sharepoint - [SharePointLMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharePointLMS)

Answer (score 1):

I always check [OpenSourceCMS](http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/show.php?catid=6&cat=Learning%20Management) when I'm looking for free software.  I'd suggest checking out [ATutor](http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/details.php?scriptid=130&name=ATutor), even if you're interested in [Moodle](http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/details.php?scriptid=137&name=Moodle).  Between those two you should be covered.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your site? Doubt it - even the lightest LMS is a serious piece of enterprise software, you may as well ask about adding a social networking application or an email client.

If you can support it and want to run an LMS you could do worse than moodle though, almost every other LMS will cost you serious amounts of money. Mostly these are toys for large institutions like banks, universities and government bodies.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to only show text data then use any open source cms from Joomla or moodle to dot net nuke but if you are looking at displaying books then you may want to consider using jalbum and other similar products out there. I believe you can embed various objects as a part of your article in these open CMS. On a side note, I have heard someone I know use a shopping cart software for outlanding the free e-learning programme lectures / notes etc by making them products and making students customers. Hope this helps. Regards, Andy